# Mongo expression with variable input

Tags: mongodb, pymongo, motorengine

I'm trying write a mongo search that can cater for two scenarios. One where the field is equal to 'False' the other when the field can be any value.

I have come up with the following:

```
  if p:
     # supposed to be my wild card expression
     mongoExp={"$eq": {"$or":[{False},{"$ne":False}}}
  else:
     # where field is equal to False
     mongoExp={"$eq": False}

  cursor=self.zel.find({"xxx": mongoExp}).sort("field1", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```

However this isn't working how can i get a wild card search with the $eq mongo operator?

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
if p:
     # supposed to be my wild card expression
     mongoExp={"$or":[{"$eq":False},{"$ne":False}]}
  else:
     # where field is equal to False
     mongoExp={"$eq": False}

  cursor=self.zel.find({"xxx": mongoExp}).sort("field1", pymongo.DESCENDING)
```